# Filter Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data on bonds. I am trying to create a dynamic filter in which I can input multiple variables based on characteristics of the data. For example, I'd like to pull all bonds that include the ticker JPM, GS, are Subordinated, and are maturing in <5yrs. However, to make it user friendly, I would like to ignore blank cells.. So, referencing the above logic, i'd also like someone to be able to simply delete the cell that defines the ticker JPM, but keep GS. Basically a multiple criteria filter that ignores blank cells.

Currently I am using the below code to start

`=FILTER(BANKSDATA,IF(ISBLANK($W$9),1,BANKSDATATICKER=$W$9)+IF(ISBLANK($W$10),1,BANKSDATATICKER=$W$10)*IF(ISBLANK($W$7),1,BANKSDATAPAYMENTRANK=$W$7))`

Basically, I am trying to filter by multiple criteria but ignore blank cells. I am able to easily do this if I do not imply the logic that I can have multiple results from the same column.. How could I show results to better explain my problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This would help if you would mock up some data and show the data and expected outputs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.